# Why Backbone view calls its model 'add' during the bind 'all' to render method? (This is backbone + node.js implementation)

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, coffeescript

So I've been having this for quite a few days. I'm working on the chat component of the application. All the communication works fine, chats are saved with Redis, Backbone controllers function just fine. The problem is rendering the chat entries in the front end. This is the problematic code:

```
class views.ChatItemView extends Backbone.View
    tagName: 'li',

    initialize: (options) ->
        console.log(@.model)
        _.bindAll @, 'render'
        @model.bind 'all', @render

    render: ->
        $(@el).html @model.get('name') + ': ' + @model.get 'text'
        @
```

This is the Firebug alert for error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object add has no method 'bind'
views.ChatItemView.ChatItemView.initializeviews.js:21
Backbone.Viewbackbone.js:884
ChatItemViewviews.js:13
views.ChatView.ChatView.addChatviews.js:76
Backbone.Events.triggerbackbone.js:117
_.extend._onModelEventbackbone.js:635
Backbone.Events.triggerbackbone.js:117
_.extend._addbackbone.js:595
_.extend.addbackbone.js:451
views.ChatView.ChatView.msgReceivedviews.js:90
NodeChatController.initcontroller.js:17
EventEmitter.emitsocket.io.js:627
SocketNamespace.onPacketsocket.io.js:2171
Socket.onPacketsocket.io.js:1861
Transport.onPacketsocket.io.js:1309
Transport.onDatasocket.io.js:1286
WS.open.websocket.onmessage
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens or did anyone have similar problem?

Comment: Is `@model.bind 'all', @render` line 21? Is `@model` a Backbone model?

Comment: @mu-is-too-short Yeah, `@model.bind 'all', @render` is line 21 and yes, @model is ChatModel as defined in controller `@model = new models.ChatModel(); @view = new views.ChatView model: @model, socket: @socket, el: $('#content')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

This is the chatView initialization code

```
class views.ChatView extends Backbone.View
    initialize: (options) ->
        @model.chats.bind 'add', @addChat
        @socket = options.socket

    msgReceived: (message) ->
            newChatEntry = new models.ChatItem
            newChatEntry.mport message.data
            @model.chats.add newChatEntry
```

It binds 'add' to the @addChat action.

```
    addChat: (chat) ->
        view = new views.ChatItemView {model: chat}
        $('#chat_list').append view.render().el
```

It works just fine this way but previously I had:

```
        @model.chats.bind 'all', @addChat
```

So, binding 'all' to @addChat was causing the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're getting your error, but, you don't need to _.bindAll when using CoffeeScript.  Just use the fat arrow for the render function:

```
class views.ChatItemView extends Backbone.View
    tagName: 'li',

    initialize: (options) ->
        console.log(@.model)
        @model.bind 'all', @render

    render: =>
        $(@el).html @model.get('name') + ': ' + @model.get 'text'
        @
```

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure about this since coffeescript aint my thing,
but

the `console.log(@.model)` seems to work? but you use `@model` when you try the bind method
shouldn't this also be

```
@.model.bind 'all', @render
```

Comment: `@.model` and `@model` both work but `@model` would be the "proper" way. There's an online CS->JS translator at http://coffeescript.org/ (hit "try coffeescript").